# How to apply inner join and find distinct value from a different table?

Tags: sql, inner-join, distinct

I have 3 SQL tables.

1. tableA
2. tableB
3. mappingAB // Contains mapping between tableA and tableB

```
db=> \d tableA
                                Table "public.tableA"
            Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id_A                       | character varying(512)   |           | not null |

db=> \d tableB
                                Table "public.tableB"
              Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id_B                         | character varying(512)   |           | not null |
 source                       | character varying(512)   |           | not null |

db=> \d mappingAB
                                Table "public.mappingAB"
            Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id_A                       | character varying(512)   |           | not null |
 id_B                       | character varying(512)   |           | not null |
```

Now, I want to find the unique values of source from tableB that relates to a single row of tableA's id_A.

Data for example:

```
tableA

 id_A
---------
 insight1
 insight2
 insight3
 insight4
 insight5

mappingAB

id_A        | id_B 
------------+--------
 insight1   | obs1
 insight1   | obs2
 insight2   | obs1
 insight2   | obs2
 insight2   | obs3
 insight3   | obs1

tableB

id_B    | source 
--------+--------
 obs1   | AWS
 obs2   | GCP
 obs3   | GCP
```

```
Expected outcome (maps source from tableB to id_A in tableA uniquely)

id_A       | AWS    | GCP
-----------+--------+-----------------------
 insight1  | 1      | 1
 insight2  | 1      | 1
 insight1  | 1      | 0
```

I want to find how many unique source are related to an id_A from tableA.

I have tried running a query like this but that fails to return the correct results.

```
select obs.source, count(obs.source)
from tableB b inner join
mappingAB ab on ab.id_B = obs.id_B
group by obs.source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cte is to get `id_A` and `source`, then using `group by` and `max` to get the expected data :

```
with cte as (
  select A.id_A, source
  from tableA A
  inner join mappingAB AB on AB.id_A = A.id_A
  inner join tableB B on AB.id_B = B.id_B
)
select id_A,
    MAX(case when source = 'AWS' then 1 else 0 end) as AWS,
    MAX(case when source = 'GCP' then 1 else 0 end) as GCP
from cte
group by id_A;
```

For previous versions that are not supporting `WITH` :

```
select A.id_A,
        MAX(case when source = 'AWS' then 1 else 0 end) as AWS,
        MAX(case when source = 'GCP' then 1 else 0 end) as GCP
from tableA A
inner join mappingAB AB on AB.id_A = A.id_A
inner join tableB B on AB.id_B = B.id_B
group by id_A
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AeX3Ram-)

Comment: No need for a cte, https://dbfiddle.uk/JCCuFd5k, (still upvoted.)

Comment: Note, _unpivot_, not pivot.

Comment: @SelVazi Thanks much. One followup: what if the source values are unknown at the time of querying? For an example, what happens to this query if there are new fields like AZURE, VMC etc. I can add them but is there any generic way of doing this?

Comment: they should be added manually, otherwise If you want it dynamically you need to use other methods depends on your DBMS